# python json dump without losing formatting

Tags: python, json, formatting, dump

For example, I have *config.json*:

```
{
  "param.a"     : 0.5,
  "param.basic" : ["x", "y"],

  "x.y.z"       : [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Load it and save to another file:

```
import json
import collections
j = json.load(open('config.json'), object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)
json.dump(j, open('new.json', 'w'), indent=4)
```

Look to *new.json*:

```
{
    "param.a": 0.5, 
    "param.basic": [
        "x", 
        "y"
    ],
    "x.y.z": [
        1, 
        2, 
        3
    ] 
}
```

Is it any simple way to make *new.json* formatting (spaces, tabs, newlines) like at *config.json*?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use collections.OrderedDict for a custom sort of your json.

```
your_json = [OrderedDict(sorted(item.iteritems(), key=lambda (k, v): sort_order.index(k)))
                for item in allsites]
```

and after

```
json.dumps(your_json, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I use it already, it's not affecting to spaces, tabs and newlines.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it any simple way to make new.json formatting (spaces, tabs, newlines) like at config.json?

Yes. Just read and write file as is:

- `input.json`

```json
{
  "param.a"     : 0.5,
  "param.basic" : ["x", "y"],

  "x.y.z"       : [1, 2, 3]
}
```

- code

```py
with open('input.json', 'rb') as i:
  with open('output.json', 'wb') as o:
    o.write(i.read())
```

- `output.json`

```json
{
  "param.a"     : 0.5,
  "param.basic" : ["x", "y"],

  "x.y.z"       : [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `json.load()` something it becomes a dict. A dict doesn't have a concept of spacing so you will not be able to use `json.dump()` directly to achieve this. You could, of course, parse the file manually and count the amount of spaces for each key. Then, you can manually write it line by line.

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with such an implementation (researched a bit and couldn't find anything). Also, implementing a one-by-one line parsing of this will make parsing and writing rather slow.